# Calling one stored procedure from another in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-3.0

I have error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to decimal'
when call stored procedure call another stored procedure from C# as

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("tax_Base_emp", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
parm1 = new SqlParameter("@emp_code", SqlDbType.BigInt); 
parm1.Value = emp_code; 
parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);
parm2 = new SqlParameter("@co_id", SqlDbType.BigInt); 
parm2.Value = Settings.Default.comp_id; 
parm2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2);
parm3 = new SqlParameter("@d", SqlDbType.DateTime); 
parm3.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("31/1/2010"); 
parm3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm3);
parm4 = new SqlParameter("@y", SqlDbType.Int); 
parm4.Value =int.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
parm4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm4);
parm5 = new SqlParameter("@check_month", SqlDbType.Int); 
parm5.Value =1; 
parm5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm5);
parm6 = new SqlParameter("@month", SqlDbType.Int); 
parm6.Value =8; 
parm6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm6);
SqlParameter parm7 = new SqlParameter("@indate", SqlDbType.DateTime); 
parm7.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("8/5/2010"); 
parm7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm7);
SqlParameter parm8 = new SqlParameter("@Sumtotal", SqlDbType.Decimal); 
parm8.Scale = 2; 
parm8.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parm8);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
decimal tax_value = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["@Sumtotal"].Value);
```

And the stored proecdure called:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE  Tax_Base_emp
  @emp_code bigint,
  @co_id bigint,
  @d datetime,
  @y int,
  @check_month int,
  @month int,
  @indate datetime,
  @Sumtotal decimal(8,2) output

AS
 declare  @tax_main_sal decimal(8,2)  
 declare  @tax_var_sal decimal(8,2)
 declare @salary decimal(8,2)
 declare @insh_varsalary decimal(8,2)
 declare @insh_value decimal(8,2)
 declare @vacation_value decimal(8,2)
 declare @vacation_varsalary decimal(8,2)
 declare @ded_value decimal(8,2) 
 declare @ben_value decimal(8,2) 


exec Taxable_mainsalary @emp_code,@co_id,@tax_main_sal output
exec taxable_varsalary @emp_code,@co_id, @tax_var_sal output
----taxableSalary---------------
set @salary=@tax_main_sal+@tax_var_sal
----insurance-------------------
exec  varsalary_insh @emp_code,@co_id,@d,@y, @insh_varsalary  output
exec insh_no @emp_code,@co_id,@insh_varsalary,@check_month, @insh_value output
----vacation--------------------
exec  vacation_varsalary @emp_code,@co_id,@vacation_varsalary output
exec  vacation_value @emp_code,@co_id,@y,@month,@vacation_varsalary,output
---------deduction--------------- 
exec deduction_for_tax @emp_code,@co_id,@indate,@ded_value output
-------------benifit------------
exec benfit_for_tax @emp_code,@co_id,@indate,@ben_value output
-----------------------------------NetSalary--------------------------------------------------------
 set @Sumtotal=(isnull(@salary,0)+isnull(@ben_value,0))-(isnull(@insh_value,0)+isnull(@vacation_value,0)+isnull(@ded_value,0))
return
```

Comment: Does the stored procedure `Tax_Base_emp` work if you call it manually in something such as Sql Server Management Studio and pass through the values that would be entered in the application?

Comment: storced procedures work in sql managment studio but problem when 
i call it from c#

Comment: @shmandor - Are you sure you're calling it with the same parameters both times? Do you have access to SQL Profiler? If so you can use that to see what is actually being sent and to trace user error messages.

Comment: @shmandor: what values are you passing to your stored proc from SQL Server Management Studio?? Are you passing the same values from C#??

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything wrong with your C# code - it's really hard to tell what would be causing the problem. Your C# code is just simply calling a single stored proc - that shouldn't be a problem, really.

However, I do have a few recommendations for your coding style:

- put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using(....) { .... }` blocks to make your code more reliable
- try to avoid specifying default property values, like `Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;` over and over again; the `.Input` is the default - only specify it when you deviate from that default
- if you do the same steps over and over and over again - why don't you put this in a method and call that method a couple of times?? This also saves you from having to create a gazillion of `SqlParameter` objects that you then just throw away .....

You'd end up with something like:

```
public void CallStoredProc()
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tax_Base_emp", con))
    {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@emp_code", SqlDbType.BigInt, emp_code);
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@co_id", SqlDbType.BigInt, comp_id);
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@d", SqlDbType.DateTime, Convert.ToDateTime("31/1/2010"));
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@y", SqlDbType.Int, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@check_month", SqlDbType.Int, 1);
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@month", SqlDbType.Int, 8);
       AddParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@indate", SqlDbType.DateTime, Convert.ToDateTime("8/5/2010"));

       AddOutputParameter(cmd.Parameters, "@Sumtotal", SqlDbType.Decimal, 8, 2);

       con.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       con.Close();

       decimal tax_value = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["@Sumtotal"].Value);
   }
}

public void AddParameter(SqlParameterCollection params, string name, SqlDbType type, object value)
{
    SqlParameter tmpParam = new SqlParameter(name, type); 
    tmpParam.Value = value; 
    params.Add(tmpParam);
}

public void AddOutputParameter(SqlParameterCollection params, string name, SqlDbType type, int precision, int scale)
{
    SqlParameter tmpParam = new SqlParameter(name, type); 
    tmpParam.ParameterDirection = Direction.Output;
    tmpParam.Precision = precision; 
    tmpParam.Scale = scale; 
    params.Add(tmpParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in the code you have posted that would cause that.

I suspect that the error is in one of the 8 stored procedures you are calling where you are assigning an nvarchar to a decimal.

I'd comment these all out temporarily and just return a dummy number if that fixes it uncomment half and try again. If the error reoccurs then you know it is in one of the ones you just uncommented. i.e. do a binary search to find the offending procedure.